# css3 animation not working in mozzila firefox

Tags: css, animation

I have make this code which results in animated background using css3 keyframes.
This code runs perfectly on chrome but it is not working in mozzila firefox.So please help me fixing this problem.
Thank You.

```
          body
    {
    -webkit-animation: HONIBHICHAYE 15s ease alternate infinite;
    -moz-animation: HONIBHICHAYE 15s ease alternate infinite;
     animation: HONIBHICHAYE 15s ease alternate infinite; 
         background-size:100%;
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-position:50% 50%;
         font-family:"My Custom Font";
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes HONIBHICHAYE
    {
        0%
        {
        background-image:url('../images/1.jpg');
        }
        50%
        {
       background-image:url('../images/2.jpg');
        }
        100%
        {
        background-image:url('../images/3.jpg');
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes HONIBHICHAYE
           {
       0%
       {
       background-image:url('../images/1.jpg');
       }
           50%
       {
       background-image:url('../images/2.jpg');
       }
        100%
      {
        background-image:url('../images/3.jpg');
      }
         }
      @keyframes HONIBHICHAYE
          {
        0%
        {
        background-image:url('../images/1.jpg');
}
           50%
        {
         background-image:url('../images/2.jpg');
         }
         100%
        {
            background-image:url('../images/3.jpg');
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have tried, the `background-image` animation does not work with Mozilla Firefox. Changing the `background-color` does work though.

Answer (score 0):

background-image is not a valid transitionable property. It works in Chrome, but it really shouldn't.